# MS2015 CppUnitTestFramework: overloading ToString for template classes

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I'm implementing complex arithmetic using variable fixed-point precision.
I've defined:

```
template <int N, int M> class FixedPoint {...}
```

And:

```
template <typename T> class Complex {...}
```

Now I want to run unit tests for different fixed-point precisions. E.g. `Complex<FixedPoint(1,4)>`, `Complex<FixedPoint(128,6)>`, `Complex<double>`, etc.

Complex representation is quite straight-forward. You just have to display the real and imaginary part. So streaming the wchar output would look like:

```
[within template class]
// output wchar stream
friend inline std::wostream& operator<< (
    std::wostream& outputStream, const Complex& object)
{
    if (object.Imaginary < 0)
    {
        // imaginary negative: sign is included
        outputStream << object.Real << object.Imaginary << "i";
    }
    else
    {
        // imaginary zero or positive: add sign
        outputStream << object.Real << "+" << object.Imaginary << "i";
    }
    return outputStream;
}
```

But now comes the issue: because the unit test framework ToString requires template specialization, and partial specialization is not allowed, I have to implement the same ToString specialization for all used data types! E.g.

```
namespace Microsoft
{
    namespace VisualStudio
    {
        namespace CppUnitTestFramework
        {
            // requires separate specializations for all implementations,
            //  because partial specialization is not allowed
            template<>
            static inline std::wstring
                ToString<Complex<Double>>(
                    const Complex<Double>& object)
            {
                RETURN_WIDE_STRING(object);
            }
            template<>
            static inline std::wstring
                ToString<Complex<FixedPoint(1,4)>>(
                    const Complex<FixedPoint(1,4)>& object)
            {
                RETURN_WIDE_STRING(object);
            }
            [etc....etc....]
        }
    }
}
```

This is a lot of seemingly redundant work! partial specialization would save me here. But that is not allowed. Does anybody have a smart idea?

Comment: Since it is really working it should suit more in here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wow this is stupid... I don't have the framework at hand, but would defining an overload instead work by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Quentin was right:

```
template<typename T>
    static inline std::wstring ToString(const Complex<T>& object)
{
    RETURN_WIDE_STRING(object);
}
```

I replaced the specialization with an overload and this did the trick. Thanks. Thinking mistake that I HAD to specialize, while overloading is just as good.